# rollapply for cumulative window

Tags: r, rollapply

I am trying to figure out how to use R rollapply on a data window which expands cumulatively from the beginning of data.

At time t, roll apply should use data in the 1:t range. At time t+1, it should use 1:t+1, and so on.

Thanks a lot
John

Comment: I googled "rollapply r" and found [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/rollapply).

Answer (score 6):

**1) rollapplyr** The `width` (2nd arg) can be a vector of widths so if `x` is some input vector and `f` is some suitable function then:

```
rollapplyr(x, seq_along(x), f)
```

For example, if `f` is `sum` then the above is the same as `cumsum(x)` and if `f` is `max` then the above is the same as `cummax(x)`.

Achim pointed out that this works too:

```
rollapplyr(x, length(x), f, partial = TRUE)
```

**2) Reduce** The above is likely what you want but, alternately, for certain functions (they must accept two arguments and iterative application must be suitable as the final answer) we can use `Reduce` in the base of R.  For example, `cumsum` and `cummmax` correspond to:

```
Reduce(`+`, x, accumulate = TRUE)
Reduce(max, x, accumulate = TRUE)
```

Note that these will not give cumulative means:

```
Reduce(mean, x, accumulate = TRUE) # BAD
Reduce(function(x, y) (x+y)/2, x, accumulate = TRUE) # BAD
```

although this does give the cumulative mean:

```
Reduce(`+`, x, accumulate = TRUE) / seq_along(x) # ok
```

so in summary `Reduce` will only work in certain restricted cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `mean`, you could try (using `base R` functions)

```
cumsum(v1)/seq_along(v1)
#[1] 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.5 3.0
```

or

```
sapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) mean(v1[1:i]))
#[1] 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.5 3.0
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c(4,2,3,1,5)
```